# Keep parent link hovered when using sublink

Tags: html, css

I have this dropdown-menu setup where i ran into trouble. The parent link needs to be in a hovered state as long as I'm using the submenu.

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #585558;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: -16px;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #585558;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fb:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.ig:hover {
  color: #fb3958;
}

.sc:hover {
  color: #fffc00;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn:hover>a {
  color: #ef5350;
}

.backslash {
  color: #8e8e8e;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Sociale medier</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="fb" target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a class="ig" target="_blank" href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a class="sc" target="_blank" href="#">Snapchat</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i make the parent link stay hovered when using the sublinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the `:hover` state.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: aqua;
}
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #585558;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 1em;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background: aqua;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 160px;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: -16px;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: #585558;
  padding: 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.fb:hover {
  color: #3b5998;
}

.ig:hover {
  color: #fb3958;
}

.sc:hover {
  color: #fffc00;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropbtn:hover>a {
  color: #ef5350;
}

.backslash {
  color: #8e8e8e;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Sociale medier</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a class="fb" target="_blank" href="#">Facebook</a>
    <a class="ig" target="_blank" href="#">Instagram</a>
    <a class="sc" target="_blank" href="#">Snapchat</a>
  </div>
</div>
```